# “Locution”, “tournure”, “expression”, “phrase” : what's the difference?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, terminologie, linguistique

For example, I don't quite understand how these two expressions are categorized in French:

- *faire tourner en bourrique*
- *a moins que*

Should I describe them as "cette locution", "cette tournure", "cette expression", "cette phrase"? It's not quite clear to me what each of these terms denotes.

Answer (score 6):

***Phrase*** is a false friend. Nowadays, it means a full sentence in French, not what English calls a phrase, although it used to only have this meaning until the eighteenth century.

The three remaining terms are somewhat overlapping:

- An ***expression*** is a phrase with a meaning, that ***exprime***<sup>1</sup> (express) something.
- A ***tournure*** is a phrase with a given style, one of the various ***tours***<sup>2</sup> (ways) to express something.
- A ***locution*** is a phrase, or a part of a phrase that is commonly used by ***locuteurs***<sup>3</sup>. It needs to be taken as a whole, can be an idiom and/or a set expression.

According to these definitions, you can say:

> ***Faire tourner en bourrique***

is an *expression idiomatique*. It means something in the French idiom, but not necessarily in other languages: literally "to turn (someone) into a "[moke](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moke)". *Bourrique* relates to *bourricot* and the Spanish *burro*.

> ***À moins que***

is a *locution conjonctive*. You can't change any part of it, it's like a single word and is a single word in English (unless). It used as a *conjonction de subordination*.

Here is an example of *tournure* usage, from the [Académie française](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/QDL066):

> *On ne saurait considérer la **tournure** « il y a pire » comme fautive, elle est simplement moins littéraire que « il y a pis »*.

<sub>1</sub> <sub>**[*Exprimer*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/exprimer)**: *Rendre sensible une réalité abstraite ou concrète en en donnant, à travers un langage approprié, une idée, une représentation, un sentiment.*</sub>
<sub>2</sub> <sub>**[*Tour*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tour/2)**: *Manière spécifique de s'exprimer, d'être exprimé; ce qui est exprimé.*</sub>
<sub>3</sub> <sub>**[*Locuteur*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tour/2)**: *Personne qui parle, qui produit des énoncés.*</sub>

Comment: Thank you. Can you show an example of "tournure"?

Comment: Example added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Certain things have a clear-cut definition but the context of synonymy between the terms blurs usage, makes it difficult, as it is a usage that is also variegated.

One of the terms can be eliminated; that's "phrase", as it means only "sentence".

**I** **locution** La définition suivante est intéressante ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/locution))

> Unité fonctionnelle du langage, composée de plusieurs mots graphiques, appartenant à la langue et devant être apprise en tant que forme globale non divisible.

The principle of definition is also stated as follows;

- Une locution est un groupe de mots qui forment une unité lexicale.

In this definition are included the "locutions" from grammar;

A first acceptation that should be taken into account is the "grammatical" sense of locution.
These locutions, except for possible grammatical changes such as due to tense, person, gender, number, are of the type of the fixed forms of the language with that particularity that they constitute parts of speech in units of several words rather than as units of one single word. Here are the types of "grammatical" locutions ([L'Obs](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/grammaire/les-locutions-225.php));

- *Locutions nominales* : faim de loup ; mise en scène ; éminence grise.
- *Locutions verbales* : prendre l'air ; faire semblant ; avoir les dents qui rayent le parquet,  en mettre sa tête à couper, jurer par tous les dieux, demander la main de qqn
- *Locutions adjectivales* : mal luné ; mi-figue, mi-raisin ; bleu des mers du sud.
- *Locutions adverbiales* : par chance ; d'ailleurs ; en vain.
- *Locutions conjonctives* : afin que ; même si ; sous réserve de.
- *Locutions prépositionnelles* : à l'aide de ; par rapport à ; vis-à-vis de.
- *Locutions pronominales*¹ : quelque chose, qui que ce puisse être, qui que ce soit, etc.
- *Locutions interjectives*¹ : on les appelle aussi locutions-phrases : Qu'importe ! Au secours !  À Dieu-vat ! Minute papillon ! Vaille que vaille ! Eh bien !

¹<sub>Ajouté à partir de [ref](http://mamiehiou.over-blog.com/article-qu-est-ce-qu-une-locution-nominale-pronominale-adjectivale-verbale-adverbiale-conjonctive-prep-92847873.html)</sub>

Latin sayings and expressions are also called "locutions" ([Le Monde](https://dicocitations.lemonde.fr/proverbes-latins.php)) and "expressions".

- Dura lex, sed lex — La loi est dure, mais c'est la loi [ Proverbe latin ]
- Ad litteram  — À la lettre  [ Proverbes latins - Expressions latines ]

**II** **tournure**

The [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/tournure/78756) provides the following definition;

> Manière dont les mots sont agencés dans un énoncé : Cette tournure appartient au français classique.

The [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tournure) adds a definition that makes the word synonymous of "expression";

> a) Manière de s'exprimer, forme donnée à un énoncé dans sa construction, sa syntaxe. Synon. formule, tour. Tournure impersonnelle, négative; tournure élégante.
>
> b) P. méton. Groupe de mots dont la construction est figée ou déterminée. Tournure idiomatique, archaïque, populaire.

- passer au fil de l'épée,

Therefore, one can say that a "locution" is a "tournure".

There is one domain of application of the word in which it caracterises also word arrangements from the grammatical point of view but as sole possibility: the words locution and  expression are not synonymous. Those are grammatical forms of verbs;

- tournure impersonnelle, tournure positive, tournure passive, tournure participiale

There is a second domain in which the word "tournure" is used to insist on syntax, on a pattern of arrangement.

- TROP DE DEUX : tournures non usitée de nos jours ; la tournure correcte est « deux de trop. » ou « deux en trop. » (C'est deux de trop. — Il y en a  deux en trop.).

**III** **expression** La définition suivante due à [l'encyclopédie libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression#Langue) apparait comme une bonne définition du mot en ce qui concerne les unités de langage;

> Une expression : un mot ou groupe de mots délimité arbitrairement selon ce que l’on souhaite étudier.

The TLFi defines "expression" as a "tour".

Il existe plusieurs sortes d'expression

1/ Les expressions idiomatiques : sauter du coq à l'âne, monter sur ses grands chevaux, …
2/ Les expressions latines [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_latine) : à priori, à postériori, etc., alea jacta est, …
3/ Il en existe d'autres, comme les expressions bibliques et les expressions régionales.